# in computed assignment A(index) OP= X, A must be defined first

Tags: octave

I typed in

> --exec_path('c:\sox-14-4-2')

to try and get octave to recognize the sound software it needs, but it returns the error code

> error: in computed assignment A(index) OP= X, A must be defined first

and I don't know why. The only thing that a google search turns up is the source code for octave, and I can't seem to find anything else on stack overflow.

I may be using the --exec_path function wrong, but I can't figure out where I messed up. If anyone can shed some light on this then that would be great!

Comment: --exec-path sets the path for subprograms from the commandline. I guess you want the function "addpath(...)" from inside Octave (which you can also add to you .octaverc)